# Why return didn't work inside my function code, but echo works, php?

Tags: php

Look at my code, if I use echo $html_of_questions, it works. If I use return, it doesn't work. Why? Should I just use echo? Because I was told I should always use return inside a function.

```
<?php

function fruit($fruit){
$questions = [
         'q1' => '<div>Is it good?</div>

                 <input type="text" value="submit"/>',
         'q2' => '<div>where is it from?</div>

                 <input type="text" value="submit"/>',
       ];

$fruit_questions = [
         'apple'  => [1,3,5],
         'banana' => [1,2,4],
         'guava' => [17,21,4],
       ];

$question_keys = $fruit_questions[$fruit];

$html_of_questions = ''; // This will hold the questions to echo
foreach($question_keys as $question_key){
    $html_of_questions .= $questions['q'.$question_key]
}

     return $html_of_questions;//doesn't work, use echo it works
}

     fruit('apple');
?>
```

Comment: You have to do something with the result, `$html = fruit('apple'); echo $html;`  That said, I would caution against returning html from a class like this.  Best Practice is to return the data and assign it to the html.  That way it is more portable, and MVC like.  Delegation of responsibility, if you want to restyle the html at a later time, it may be much harder to find buried in a class or function somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works, you just don't do anything with the result:

```
fruit('apple');
```

If you want to echo the result, you'd have to echo it:

```
echo fruit('apple');
```

Or perhaps store it in a variable and later do something with it:

```
$result = fruit('apple');
// other code
echo $result;
```

Just calling a function doesn't tell the system to do anything with the result of that function.  The function simply encapsulates an operation and returns a result.  You then have to do something with the result.

Comment: Thank you very much. I got it.